# How to draw on standart button WinApi

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi

I want to draw a simple square on a button.

I created a regular window and a regular button in it. Now, in the window procedure of my window, in the `WM_PAINT` message, I get the `HDC` of my button and draw a square:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND   hWnd, UINT   message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{

    if (message == WM_PAINT)
    {
        PAINTSTRUCT ps;
        HDC my_hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);


        //---------------------------------------------
        HDC my_button_HDC = GetDC(GetDlgItem(hWnd, 11));  //Get HDC my button

        Rectangle(my_button_HDC, 5, 5, 30, 30);
        //---------------------------------------------


        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
}


WinMain()
{
//standart code create window and button...
}
```

When creating a window, a square does not appear on the button. It appears ONLY when I move my window down outside of the screen and lift it up.
[image]

But, as soon as I resize the window or click on the button, the square disappears again.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Comment: [Subclassing Controls](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/subclassing-overview).

Comment: IInspectable, unfortunately did not understand how it solves the problem and what the problem is.

Comment: The problem is that the button paints itself and obliterates what you have painted. To change the appearance of the control you need to subclass it so you can intercept the painting message and modify its behavior.

Comment: Jonathan Potter, thank you, please tell me, where can I see an example, what message needs to be intercepted and how to reconfigure it?

Comment: [Subclassing the Window Class of an Existing Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/user-controls-intro#subclassing-the-window-class-of-an-existing-control).

Answer (score 1):

You are drawing on the button only when its *parent* window is being painted (also, you are leaking the button's `HDC`).  Resizing the window does not always trigger a repaint.

But even when it does, when the button itself paints itself, it will draw over anything you have already drawn.

The *correct* way to draw on a standard Win32 button is to either:

- give the button the `BS_OWNERDRAW` style, and then have its *parent* window handle the [`WM_DRAWITEM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/wm-drawitem) message.
- if `ComCtl32.dll` v6 is being used (see [Enabling Visual Styles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cookbook-overview)), the *parent* window can instead handle the [`NM_CUSTOMDRAW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/nm-customdraw-button) message, `BS_OWNERDRAW` is not needed.  See [Custom Draw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/custom-draw) for more details.